# How can I set up an integral for work? I have an integral for water, a distance the water needs to be moved, and the weight of water per inch.

Tags: calculus, integration, mathematical-physics

I have an image attached that explains this project in more detail. enter image description here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tfioo.jpg)I need help with part g. I need help just setting up the correct interval. I know what to do afterwards, but I need to set up the correct integral in order to solve anything else.
I know that I have my integral for volume of water. I also know that I have my distance with the straw. I also know the weight of water.

How am I supposed to combine these together to make a formula for work? 
I know Work requires a Force function, such as: 
F= mass times acceleration, 
F=density times volume times acceleration,
F=density times gravity times surface area of a fluid times height of fluid

Which equation am I supposed to use? Am I even on the right track? Please help, as I am taking Calculus 2 online, and my teacher is largely unavailable. Also, you may edit my question as needed. I am new to this community and am new to figuring things out, so please do not down vote without notifying me of any issues, as I want to be helpful in maintaining this community.

Answer (score 0):

You are lifting disks of water of volume $A(x)dx$ up a distance $h-x$ where $h$ =height of straw and $A(x)$ = area of cup at height $x$. So integrate that (multiplied by density times g) over the depth of the water.